# What's the jQuery selector for this very similar case?

Tags: jquery

I have three a tags that I cannot edit their HTML:

```
<a onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" id="content-html">Text</a>

<a rel="popover" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html content-bootstrap" id="content-html" onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);">Syntax</a>

<a onclick="" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" id="content-tmce">Visual</a>
```

They are very similar but but I would like to select only the first one:

```
 <a onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" id="content-html">Text</a>
```

Any ideas whats the best and most stable jQuery selector for this? Thanks.

Cheers.

**UPDATE:** Changing this ID is possible but I have edit the WordPress core(also not recommended). Currently there is no other filter provided to do this. In /wp-admin/js/editor.min.js they grab the value of the ID for processing the tab switching mechanism(tinymce to text editor vice versa). I added a third link (Syntax) to have the same functionality as the HTML/text editor except that I would instantiate CodeMirror later on.

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page. Your HTML code is invalid

Comment: Thanks Roasted..yes I know..I'm still on the process of digging deeper how to change this one..Currently if I change that in Firebug, it breaks functionality. So I need to have selector working first..

Comment: No, you have to get valid code first because you'll stuck earlier or later...

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but if your links each have different tasks you could differentiate them by having an additional CSS class in each (or a data- attribute) and using that in your selector.

Comment: Yes I know its a possible way, but I have updated my question..I'm using WP that only processes ID instead of class in that said core JS script. And I need to get the same functionality of the result for that same id containing content-html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a.wp-switch-editor:first")
```

this Should work for you , refer this for more 
[refer :first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

It has an ID, so use that:

```
$("#content-html")
```

As @adam points out in his comment, you have multiple ID's. While this selector will still select the first one, you should NOT repeat your ID's.

Comment: The second link has the same id - not sure how jQuery handles this. If it just takes the first, then this is great.

Comment: It will take the first in the collection, ID's should be unique anyway

Comment: @AKA -- The OP has invalid HTML, there's no point in putting a `first` selector when you're grabbing an ID.

Comment: tymeJV is right, as jquery selector for ID returns only first matched element, not like this one: `$('[id="content-html"]')` which is used on really bad coded sites like OP's one

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.wp-switch-editor').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("[id=content-tmce]")` will select all elements with `content-tmce` id

`$("#content-tmce")` will select only first element